# Set div's content position

Tags: css

I've got several divs in a row with text1, breaking, and text2.
Here is an example:

```css
.testDiv {
    border: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 row">
    <div class="col-2 testDiv">
        <p>LineTop1</p>
        <hr />
        <p>LineBot</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 testDiv">
        <p>LineTop1</p>
        <hr />
        <p>LineBot</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 testDiv">
        <p>LineTop1 LineTop1 LineTop1</p>
        <hr />
        <p>LineBot</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 testDiv">
        <p>LineTop1</p>
        <hr />
        <p>LineBot</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 testDiv">
        <p>LineTop1</p>
        <hr />
        <p>LineBot</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Code Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paprikano/9eaqg5jt/7/)

As you can see on the third div, if text1 is longer and go to a new line, the height of all divs is changing.
Now, how can I get the result like this:

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI2Lt.png)

So even if divs are getting higher, I want text2 in all divs in the same line (something like margin-bottom 0 for text2).

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. All code relevant to your problem, belongs directly into your question. Do not _just_ dump it onto external platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `min-height` property to your p tag and add a class with min-height set.

**Example would be this:**

```css
.testDiv {
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.eq-height {min-height:75px;}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 row">
  <div class="col-2 testDiv">
    <p class="eq-height">LineTop1</p>
    <hr />
    <p>LineBot</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 testDiv">
    <p class="eq-height">LineTop1</p>
    <hr />
    <p>LineBot</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 testDiv">
    <p class="eq-height">LineTop1 LineTop1 LineTop1</p>
    <hr />
    <p>LineBot</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 testDiv">
    <p class="eq-height">LineTop1</p>
    <hr />
    <p>LineBot</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 testDiv">
    <p class="eq-height">LineTop1</p>
    <hr />
    <p>LineBot</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` (will few tweeks if needed). This will automatically take care of heights.

**Updated Fiddle Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/fw93tc0y/4/

```css
.testDiv {
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.testDiv p:first-child{
  flex:1;
  border-bottom:1px solid #777;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 row">
  <div class="col-2 testDiv">
    <p>LineTop1</p>
   
    <p>LineBot</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 testDiv">
    <p>LineTop1</p>
   
    <p>LineBot</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 testDiv">
    <p>LineTop1 LineTop1 LineTop1</p>
    
    <p>LineBot</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 testDiv">
    <p>LineTop1</p>
  
    <p>LineBot</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 testDiv">
    <p>LineTop1</p>
    
    <p>LineBot</p>
  </div>
</div>
```